# Exceptions in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data application (using Entity Framework) in which I have just discovered a duplicate key error when attempting a database insert.  However, I had to use SQL Profiler to find the error.  The insert template page just silently did nothing.

How can I trap errors like this and log them and maybe display a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions can be detected, if not caught, in the CUD event arguments on the DetailsView and the DataSource controls, e.g. events such as `DetailsView_ItemInserted`, and `DetailsDataSource_Inserting` have `Exception Exception` and `bool ExceptionHandled` properties for handling exceptions.

Comment: If you are handling the exception, make sure to set the ExceptionHandled property to True so that it responds back to the front end correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you could implement in Dynamic Data site is using a custom derived **DynamicValidator** control.

For detail information, please, refer to the link [Handling database exceptions in Dynamic Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/12/11/handling-database-exceptions-in-dynamic-data.aspx)